# pg-promise - unable to receive db response back when use batch

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise

I'm trying to get a response back from the database when I use tx.batch.

Thanks.

- 1) query db for pre-existing records that need to be updated
- 2) using results from 1, make another batch call to db to either
  create or update records
- 3) respond back with status 200 to my api with records created and
  records updated

Batch calls does work, verified records are inserted or/and updated into db.

```
 db.tx(t1 => {
    let queryCheck = [];

    reqData.forEach(obj => {
      for (let key in obj) {
        obj[key].resovledURLs.forEach(data => {
          queryCheck.push(
            t1.any(
              `SELECT * FROM testDB WHERE url='${key}' AND testurl='${data}';`
            )
          );
        });
      }
    });

    return t1
      .batch(queryCheck)
      .then(data => {

        return t1.tx(t2 => {
          let t2QueryBatch = [];

         // got rid of queryBatchOfEverything()
         // uses data from t1.batch(queryCheck) to make joinedArray
         let joinedArray = updateArray.concat(createArray);

          joinedArray.forEach(obj => {
            if (obj.queryType === "Update") {
              t2QueryBatch.push(
                t2.none(
                  `UPDATE testDB SET count = count + 1 WHERE url='${
                    obj.url
                  }' AND errorurl='${obj.testurl}';`
                )
              );
            } else {
              t2QueryBatch.push(
                t2.none(
                  `INSERT INTO testDB (url, testurl) VALUES ('${
                    obj.url
                  }', '${obj.testurl}');`
                )
              );
            }
          });

          return t2.batch(t2QueryBatch);
        });
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code exhibits so many problems, it is impossible to advise on the exact issue. You would need to revise the code thoroughly before any further diagnostics is even possible.

### Immediately noticeable problems in your code...

#### problem 1

You forget to chain `queryBatchOfEverything` to the transaction that contains it, i.e. it should be `return queryBatchOfEverything...`, if that's your transaction logic

#### problem 2

You open a nested transaction on the `db` object, which is invalid, i.e. you cannot create an independent top-level transaction while inside another transaction.

You can only create a sub-transaction there, aka `savepoint`, from the context of the parent transaction, i.e. `t1.tx(t2 => {})`.

#### problem 3

You forget to chain the result of the nested transaction into the parent transaction, so another loose promise on your hands. It needs to be `return t1.tx(t2 => )`

#### problem 4

You use method `one` inside the nested transaction, which means you expect exactly one row of data back, while none of your queries return anything, i.e. you are supposed to use method `none` there instead. This is the very problem that you asked about. But you need to fix the rest in order for the whole to work right.

#### problem 5

You do not chain `t2.batch` to the transaction, creating another loose promise. It should be `return t2.batch`.

#### problem 6

This is not a problem, just some useless code:

```
let updateRecords = await t1.batch(queryCheck).then(data => {
    return data;
});
```

It is exactly the same as this:

```
let updateRecords = await t1.batch(queryCheck);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my errors, I think I've made all the changes you mentioned, so I no longer get the error message, but now I get : [ null, null, null ]. Where did I wrong?

Comment: @DavidTrinh If you return `batch[none, none, none]`, it will resolve into `[null, null, null]`, as expected, since `none` resolves with `null` when successful.